# Passing a QString to a class method of parent with QSignalMapper

Tags: c++, qt, qsignalmapper

I have a parent class with its method to change a labels picture on certain Signals. E.g. When something happens in a QComboBox... (valueChanged, activated)

```
    class parentClass : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        ...

    public slots:
        //this is the slot i want to connect to some signal of
        //e.g a combo box to change the picture by passed in string 
        void changePicture(QString fileName);
```

Then i have this child:

```
    class childClass : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        childClass(parentClass *parent, QTabWidget *tab, QStringList *guards=0);

    private:
        bool readCombo(QXmlStreamReader *xmlreader);
```

Now inside of `readCombo` i want to read a string and pass it to change picture:

```
    QString imageFileName = xmlreader->attributes().value("image").toString(); 

    QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(parent);

    //this is just one of many trials to get this working, i hope you get the picture

    connect(combo , SIGNAL(activated(int)), parent, SLOT(changePicture(QString *)));

    signalMapper->setMapping(combo, imageFileName);
```

But this gives me either `No such Signal` , `No such Slot` or in the upper case `Incompatiple sender/receiver arguments`

I would appreciate some help on this one since the syntax is really not being intuitive (imo) and i can't find any good reference that is working for my case (did trial and error a lot before asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it:

```
QString imageFileName = xmlreader->attributes().value("image").toString(); 

QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(parent);

signalMapper->setMapping(combo, imageFileName);

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), parent, SLOT(changePicture(QString)));

connect( combo, SIGNAL(activated(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with your code.

1. you really can't connect to a private slot of a `QObject`
2. You are creating a new signal mapper every time you call `readCombo` which you aren't clearing - resulting memleaks.
3. calling `connect` multiple times creates multiple connections i.e., you will call the same slot multiple times with single signal.

From your example code, I see that you can solve this either by making the `parentClass` slot public OR add a signal to the `childClass` and connect to it in the `parentClass`.

Other option is change the `readCombo` like this:

```
QString imageFileName = xmlreader->attributes().value("image").toString();
parentClass->changePicture(imageFileName);
```

and your parent class as

```
class parentClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...

public slots:
    //this is the slot i want to connect to some signal of
    //e.g a combo box to change the picture by passed in string 
    void changePicture(QString fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how will this pass `fileName` as an argument to `changePicture` when a `SIGNAL` like `activated` is emitted?

Comment: from your code, it looks like you already have `imageFileName` constructed from `xmlreader`. You aren't using `activated` signal there, right?

Comment: OK, i will probably need to explain the background to this: I want a picture in a label only to be changed when a signal is emitted. For a `QPushButton` this would just be `clicked` but there is no such signal for a `QComboBox` (or?). So every combo instance would show another picture when it is being changed or whatever...

Answer (score 1):

I see several errors:

1. You are connecting to a private slot in `parentClass` from `childClass`, you should make it public if you want to connect it.
2. You connect a signal to a slot with another function signature. Your signal has parameter type `int`, and slot type `QString*`. The functions should share the same type of parameters.
3. In your connect you refer use the parameter type `QString*` in your slot, but in `parentClass` the parameter type is `QString`.

For more information about signals and slots see: [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

PS: your naming of `childClass` and `parentClass` is not clear either since they both inherit from `QObject`. See [C++ inheritance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm).

Comment: Yes this seems like bad programming anyway and i only shall implement those changes :) I will have to go through C++ inheritance while transiting from Python to C++

Comment: And [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) reference is a bit short information on a bit larger topic, isn't it?